# Relation between Photochemical reactions and Photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, photoelectric-effect, quantum-chemistry

I was writing my lab report of determining the value of Planck's Constant using photoelectric effect. Suddenly, a question stuck my mind that in photoelectric effect electrons are ejected from molecules because of the energy supplied to them by light photons and similarly in Photochemical reactions also electrons take part in the reaction by the action of light.

I therefore thought may be Photochemical reactions are initiated by photoelectric effect. Please correct me if I am wrong or if I am correct please give some sources to help me to study about it in more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I therefore thought may be Photochemical reactions are initiated by photoelectric effect.

I am not quite sure if I understand correctly what you mean by "initiated", but in my opinion in this generality the statement is not correct.

You are right that in both cases the sample is irradiated by a beam of photons. If you observe a photoelectric effect, it means that the energy of your photons is high enough to completely eject an electron from the molecule. Or in other words: the energy of your photons needs to reach a minimum threshold in order to emit photoelectrons.

What happens if the energy of your irradiating beam is not high enough to separate an electron from the molecule (i.e. no photoelectrons)? Then there is still the possibility that by absorbing the radiation the molecule reaches an excited state. The properties of the molecules in an excited state can differ a lot from those in the ground state (before irradiation) And this is where most of the magic of photochemistry happens.

For example, by absorbing light the molecule **rhodopsin** in the human eye changes its shape which in the following triggers a reaction that lead to an electrochemical signal for the brain. The photoelectric effect is not needed for this explanation.